# How to calculate and store the number in scientific notation?

Tags: python-3.x, physics, scientific-notation

I am using Python to model the statistical physical, so I will deal with small numbers.

For example,

```
a = 2.22e-300, b = 3e-200
```

and I want to calculate

```
a * b = 6.66e-500.
```

However, in Python 3 it shows 0.0.

I am thinking to design a data type: the first part to store the float number, which is 6.66 here, and the second part stores the magnitude, which is -500.

May I ask how I can implement this? Or is there any better way to deal with the scientific number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a class:

```
class Sci_note:
    def __init__(self, base, exp):
        self.base = base
        self.exp = exp
    def __mul__(self, other):
        return Sci_note(self.base * other.base,
                        self.exp + other.exp)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.base) + 'e' + str(self.exp)
```

and it functions as you would expect:

```
>>> a = Sci_note(2.22, -300)
>>> b = Sci_note(3, -200)
>>> c = a * b
>>> c.base
6.66
>>> c.exp
-500
```

---

**update**

I added a `__str__` method (above), so they are displayed properly when printed:

```
>>> print(a)
2.22e-300
```

---

Of course, I have only implemented the multiplication method here, but I will leave it up to you to implement the others when required. It may be the case that you only need multiplication so I would be wasting everyone's time if I wrote them now!

In addition, creating a `__float__` handler would also not be useful here, as Python *can't* handle floats of the order `^-300`, so it would be useless to return them as we would just get `0`!

Comment: Neat that your class is more accurate than `decimal` library.

Comment: @kabanus Yes, since Python converts any `e` notation to floats immediately and floats only have finite precision, so no matter what library you use that tries to store `2.22 ^ -300` (**very** small), it will loose its value and become `0` which yields the OP's problem of returning `0` when multiplying :)

Comment: @csl This never directly deals with the minuscule floating points like `2.22 ^ -300`, it stores the base and exponents separately, so they don't loose precision.

Comment: Although this code is neat, I'd not recommend anyone to write their own fixnum class unless they have extremely specific needs.

Comment: BTW, Joe, you should provide cast operators.

Comment: @kabanus please elaborate... what needs casting exactly?

Comment: @kabanus Yes, I deleted that comment because it clearly is fixpoint. But still, you quickly want other operators, deal with conversion etc. And that will quickly become tedious.

Comment: @Joe Doesn't "need" per-say but it would be nice if `float(Sci_note(1.1,10))` would work. And it's a short line, as well.

Comment: @csl Is that your DV?... because you have said that your point didn't apply here.

Comment: @kabanus I have addressed that now! See if you type in `2e-300` to the interpreter, you get `0` (after forcing Python to convert it properly to a float, e.g. : `2e-300 + 1 - 1`), so returning a float is pointless unless the OP plans to use this with smaller numbers.

Comment: @kabanus No problem

Comment: This is cool, thank you. I don't need so precise number like 1.00000000000001e-100, so this would work pretty well. For the multiplication, we may also need to consider carry, but it won't be an issue.

Comment: @AugustinPan Thanks, please accept since it works then.

Answer (score 3):

I strongly suggest you use something like the built-in [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) module and increase its precision to your needs. For example:

```
>>> from decimal import *
>>> getcontext().prec = 100
>>> a = Decimal("2.22e-300")
>>> b = Decimal("3e-200")
>>> a
Decimal('2.22E-300')
>>> b
Decimal('3E-200')
>>> a*b
Decimal('6.66E-500')
```

Note that, to be on the safe side, I create `a` and `b` using *strings* such as `"3e-200"` to let the `decimal` module parse them correctly. If not, it will first convert them to Python's inexact floating points and muck them up before passing them into `Decimal` objects.

In the above code, we set the precision to 100.